# continuous duplicate of same error report on my site as pasted below

Tags: error, reports

my site keep giving me same report as paste below, please how do solved this issue?

a:5:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:409:"#0 /home/thewa2m2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(179): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')

Comment: the error still continue pls how resolve it                                                              a:5:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:409:"#0 /home/thewa2m2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(179): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')

Answer (score 1):

This often happens for two reasons,

1. You removed/added/changed a module without disabling the configuration cache first
2. Configuration cache corruption

---

## To solve 1.

Clear your configuration cache and if the issue is resolved, nothing further is required.

---

## To Solve 2.

This is a core-code bug in some versions of Magento. You can test if it is caused by this bug by editing `Mage_Core_Model_Config` to reflect the following.

```
public function init($options=array())
{
    $this->setCacheChecksum(null);
    $this->_cacheLoadedSections = array();
    $this->setOptions($options);
    $this->loadBase();

    $cacheLoad = $this->loadModulesCache();
    if ($cacheLoad) {
        return $this;
    }
+   $this->_useCache = false;

    $this->loadModules();
    $this->loadDb();
    $this->saveCache();
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: this error did not stop  a:5:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:409:"#0 /home/thewa2m2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(179): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')

Comment: this error did not stop

Comment: https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug/#debugging-the-issue

@emmanuel Have a look there, it was how I initially debugged the `_useCache = false` solution. It could help suppress the issue and gather more useful debug data!

Answer (score 0):

As seen from the message, the problem occurs because your routers are making circular references for dispatching requests. One of them matches request, but doesn't dispatch and pushes it to redispatch again. Or no router matches request at all.
I cant directly tell the cause of this error, but can work with you to get the cause of it.
In order to debug it first open **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php** and find these lines or somewhat similar

```
    while (!$request->isDispatched() && $i++<100) { 
      foreach ($this->_routers as $router) { 

      }
    }
```

and replace it with (take the backup of the file)

```
Mage::log('----Matching routers------------------------------');
Mage::log('Total ' . count($this->_routers) . ': ' . implode(', ', array_keys($this->_routers)));
while (!$request->isDispatched() && $i++<100) {
    Mage::log('- Iteration ' . $i);
    $requestData = array(
        'path_info' => $request->getPathInfo(),
        'module' => $request->getModuleName(),
        'action' => $request->getActionName(),
        'controller' => $request->getControllerName(),
        'controller_module' => $request->getControllerModule(),
        'route' => $request->getRouteName()
    );

    $st = '';
    foreach ($requestData as $key => $val) {
        $st .= "[{$key}={$val}]";
    }
    Mage::log('Request: ' . $st);
    foreach ($this->_routers as $name => $router) {
        if ($router->match($this->getRequest())) {
            Mage::log('Matched by "' . $name . '" router, class ' . get_class($router));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

after that wait for the site to produce the error. then open your system.log file and see whats going wrong ? what router break ?

Ideally this issue arises once magento is not able to load a core module.

If you have trouble to find out the solution. Let me know I will try to help you.

Comment: hi, thanks for helping me on this issue but after adding the code you displace above the situation still continue but this time is different error report... pls view below and tell me what to do.. a:5:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:409:"#0 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(196): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')

Comment: can u post complete error ?

Comment: make sure you are checking both system.log and exception.log file

Comment: aslo is Index controller of the cms module is overridden ?

Comment: have you deleted 404 page ?

Comment: the error at exception.log are exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Trbanner_Block_Trbanner' in /home/thewa2m2/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0

Comment: pls assist me on it

Comment: check your Mage_Trbanner module specially its layout.xml. It is not able to find the block  Trbanner. Also us your index controller of cms module is overridden ? or have you deleted 404 page in dashboard ?

Comment: no i have not delete the 404 page in my dashboard, should i delete it?